# Visual studio 2022 error while creating a controller via scaffolding, "there was an error getting the type.(model name), try rebuilding the project."

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller, scaffolding

I am trying to follow a yt tutorial https://youtu.be/OLBmtRFFwcQ?si=MIb_Y9mXzgGpk51y at around 8 mins, I encountered this problem

[image]

after a quick bing search it says that I am missing something in my Visual studio, idk what it is and kinda stuck in this problem now, just a newbie in this backend stuff please be considerate :>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed this problem by rebuilding the solution and updating NuGet packages.